# java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl cannot be cast to DocumentBuilderFactory

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mocking, easymock, powermock

I am using powermock with **powermock-easymock-1.5-full.jar**. The following exception occurs.

These are the all jars i have in my classpath. And are downloaded as powermock package from http://code.google.com/p/powermock/downloads/detail?name=powermock-easymock-testng-1.5.zip&can=2&q=

1. easymock-3.1.jar
2. javassist-3.17.1-GA.jar
3. jcommander-1.27.jar
4. objenesis-1.2.jar
5. snakeyaml-1.6.jar
6. testng-6.8.jar
7. bsh-2.0b4.jar
8. cglib-nodep-2.2.2.jar
9. powermock-easymock-1.5-full.jar

```
    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.eibus.localization.message.MessageSet._tryGetMessageText(MessageSet.java:268)
    at com.eibus.localization.message.Message._tryGetMessage(Message.java:135)
    at com.eibus.localization.message.Message.getMessage(Message.java:110)
    at com.eibus.localization.message.Message.getMessageWithLocaleFallBack(Message.java:155)
    at com.eibus.localization.StringFormatter.getMessageWithFallBack(StringFormatter.java:141)
    at com.eibus.localization.StringFormatter.format(StringFormatter.java:43)
    at com.eibus.localization.LocalizableComposite.getMessage(LocalizableComposite.java:42)
    at com.eibus.localization.exception.LocalizableException.getMessage(LocalizableException.java:168)
    at com.eibus.localization.exception.LocalizableException.getLocalizedMessage(LocalizableException.java:130)
    at java.lang.Throwable.toString(Throwable.java:479)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.println(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintWriter.println(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:654)
    at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:720)
    at org.junit.runner.notification.Failure.getTrace(Failure.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestListener.testFailure(JUnit4TestListener.java:68)
    at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier$4.notifyListener(RunNotifier.java:100)
    at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier$SafeNotifier.run(RunNotifier.java:41)
    at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier.fireTestFailure(RunNotifier.java:97)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.addFailure(MethodRoadie.java:154)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.handleException(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:359)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit49RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit49MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit49RunnerDelegateImpl.java:93)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:284)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:84)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:209)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:148)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:122)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:101)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Please help me

Comment: did u get any solution?

Answer (score 17):

Here is something that worked for me:

```
@PowerMockIgnore({"javax.xml.*", "org.xml.sax.*", "org.w3c.dom.*",  "org.springframework.context.*", "org.apache.log4j.*"})
```

Answer (score 5):

If this is a PowerMock related problem, then you can try to annotate you test class with:

```
@PowerMockIgnore({"javax.xml.parsers.*", "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.*"})
```

Comment: The above trick is not working for me. The interesting part is I get the above exception only when there is a problem(which can through some exception) in my test code. Instead of throwing actual exception it is always throwing the above ClassCastException.

Comment: The exception is thrown when log4j is invoked. it's not really related with exceptions

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore the log4j.*. I have the same problem with jptool logger. And I already resolved by ignoring it 
Here is my code
@PowerMockIgnore({"jptools.*"})

Answer (score 0):

This is a PowerMock problem, I had this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class sun.security.provider.ConfigFile
```

that you can resolve with this annotation, try to annotate you test class with :

```
@PowerMockIgnore({"javax.management.*", "java.lang.*", "javax.security.*" })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `configuration.properties` file in `test/resources/org/powermock/extensions/` with content:

```
powermock.global-ignore=org.apache.xerces.*,javax.xml.parsers.*,org.xml.sax.*
```

Note: Comma separation and NO spaces in the property value, otherwise, it will not work!
The list of packages depends on the dependencies of your project.

PowerMock Configuration [here](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/PowerMock-Configuration).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with PowerMock v1.5.1 and Log4j 2.19.0

To fix it, I added `org.apache.logging.logj4.*` to my existing `@PowerMockIgnore` annotation like so:

```
@PowerMockIgnore({"javax.management.*", "org.apache.logging.log4j.*"})
-- Irrelevant annotations removed for brevity --
public class DeclarationRulesDelegateTest extends RulesTest {
```